# How i show an alert message in my iphone using rhomobile

Tags: iphone, rhomobile

How i show an alert message in my iphone using rhomobile?

Thanks,
Companion

Answer (score 2):

You use Alert.show_message:

http://wiki.rhomobile.com/index.php/RhodesDeviceCapabilities#Alerts

Comment: this link is obsolete. This one works now: http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhodes/device-caps#alerts

Answer (score 0):

its pretty easy - Here's an example from my app.  It pops up a momentary alert with a global variable I had set called @@remote_version and then hides after 2 seconds.

```
Alert.show_popup :message=> 'Indexing Department List v.' + @@remote_version, :title => 'One Moment Please'
sleep 2
Alert.hide_popup
```

Hope that helps.
 -Jon